# Transitivity for sets.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose one has $f(A)=D_0$ and $f(D_{n})=D_{n+1}$, where f is a 1-1 function. Furthermore, $D_{n}\subset D_{n-1}\subset A$. Take $D = \cap_{n=0}^\infty D_n$ but $D\not=\emptyset$. (I changed part of the question because of something written by fleablood). Is there a simple way of proving that $|A|=|D|$. (Is this even true?)

Comment: Is that even true?  $A = (0,1)= D_0; f(x) = x/2; D_n = (0, 1/2^n); D = \emptyset$?

Comment: It is probably not true, but why? Why can't one use transitivity an infinite amount of times?

Comment: Also, what is your function and how is it 1-1 and onto?

Comment: Why do you think that you *can* use "transitivity" (in what sense?)?

Comment: If $|A| = |D_0|$ and $|D_0| = |D_n|$ then $|A| = |D_n|$. I now assume that given how this is proven it only works in the finite case.

Comment: @YitzchakShmalo, yes. Compare with the obvious example of the infinite union of finite sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two points here:

1. If you could claim that $\bigcap D_n$ is the image under $f$ of $A$ at the $\omega$-th iterate, and that $\omega$-th iterate is injective, there would be no problem.
2. But you can't use that, because it's false. You can easily concoct injections from $\Bbb N$ to itself such that the intersection $\bigcap f^k(\Bbb N)$ is empty, finite of any prescribed size, or infinite.

This is not about applying transitivity infinitely many times as much as this is a problem with the fact that the intersection of the repeated images of $A$ is not an image of $A$ under the same injective function. What fails here is the fact that iterating a function infinitely many times need not be defined or preserve properties like injectivity or surjectivity.

Answer (score 1):

False with almost the same example of fleablood: $A=[0,1]$, $f(x) = x/2$, $D_n = [0,1/2^n]$.